# In SQL Server, I want to use the same query for all the tables in a database

Tags: sql-server

I need to find a way to perform the same query to all the tables in an specific database.

For example, if my database `DB` has the tables `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`, `Table4` and `Table5`, I want to perform the query

```
SELECT * FROM <All 5 Tables>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Why? It makes the query less readable. If you go back to it in 2 years time, will you understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
USE [DB]
exec sp_msforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM ?'
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: this is an **undocumented** stored proc and it might suddenly vanish without a trace....

Comment: You will find examples about so_msforeachtable and sp_msforeachdb at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-exec-sp_msforeachdb-sp_msforeachtable-example-tsql-code.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable N'SELECT * FROM ?'
```

Comment: Im trying to do the following query:

USE [DreamHome]
exec sp_msforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM ? where xtype = ''U'''

but it is not working, I also tried to define an escape value and didnt work

 what am i doing wrong ???

Comment: @user1073816: do all your tables have a `xtype` column???

Comment: yes, but the problem here is that sql server is not recognizing the escape for the single columns inside my string

Comment: correction: the xtype column is in the sys.tables of each table so probably this filter should be outside of the string, but how do i do this filter, i mean i want to display only tables created by an user.